# Format/ group list of strings by condition

Tags: c#, list

I have a question regarding formatting List of strings. I'm looping through dictionary of two strings: value and tagname.

```
myList.Add(myDict.Keys.ElementAt(n) + ":" + myDict.Values.ElementAt(n).Value);
```

When the iteration is done, I need to format that string as follows:

```
for (int tmp = 0; tmp < myList.Count; tmp++)
{
    if (tmp < myList.Count - 1)
    {
        tempString += String.Format(myList[tmp].ToString() + " ,");
    }
}
```

Output of that tempstring will be like this: TagName: Value, TagName: Value, TagName: Value.
But here's the tricky part (for me): several tag names are the same, and for the program purposes, these items which have same tag name needs to be grouped by that tag name, something like this:
TagName: value, TagName: value, value, value
Do you have any suggestions for this?

Update (reading XML):

```
    var evt = (from el in doc.Descendants("test")
       where el.Parent.Name == "Event_1"
       group el by el.Parent.Element("NameOfEvent").Value into g
       select new {
           Name = g.Key,
           Tests = g.Select(x => new {
               Value = x.Element("value").Value,
               TagName = x.Element("tagName").Value
           })
       }).FirstOrDefault();

     Console.WriteLine("Event name: " + evt.Name);
     foreach (var test in evt.Tests)
     {

     }
```

Comment: How do you have `TagName`'s that are the same if you are using them for your dictionary keys?

Comment: It's not clear, can you show a small sample dictionary and how you extract the list? Do you need the list at all? Why do you add the same key multiple times to the list?

Comment: The key of a dictionary is unique. So how could you have duplicated tag name as tag name is the key of the dictionary?

Comment: I'm reading values and tag names from XML. I put the same tag name for the values that are need to be grouped by that one specific tag name. I can change that, but not sure what I can accomplish.

Comment: `Dictionary`'s require keys to be unique, so your program is throwing an error, or the keys are not unique

Comment: @CharlesNRice TagName is value. For Example: Key= "SomeString", Value= "TagName"

Comment: Why don't you show how you are reading XML. You might not even need the list

Comment: @CharlesNRice I have updated question, please see updates (reading XML).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a combination of LINQ's [Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) and [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) takes a list of objects and produces a list of lists of objects where each list's objects all contain something in common.

```
{"Key1", "Value1"},
{"Key2", "Value2"},
{"Key1", "Value3"}
```

Becomes

```
{
   {"Key1", "Value1"},
   {"Key1", "Value3"}
},
{
   {"Key2", "Value2"},
}
```

When you group all of the values by their values. Then you can just take that result and join the values in a comma separated list using [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

What you want to do is construct a list that contains all of your values grouped together under the same key and then join them into a string.

There are 3 steps to do this:

1. Group value by tag
2. Construct a string for each of the values for each tag
3. Construct the final string from each of the other constructed strings

Which would look something like this:

```
// Your keys and values
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> dict = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TagName1", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TagName2", "value2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TagName1", "value3")
};

// 1. Group all of the values together based on the key
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>> groupedValues = 
            dict.GroupBy(v => v.Key);

// 2. Construct a string for each of the groups
IEnumerable<string> builtValues = groupedValues.Select(group =>
{
    // returns "TagName1:value1, value2" etc.
    return group.Key + ":" + string.Join(", ", group.Select(g => g.Value));
});

// 3. Construct the final string from each of the constructed strings
string finalResult = string.Join(", ", builtValues);
```

Then `finalResult` would contain `TagName1:value1, value3, TagName:value2`, which seems to be relatively what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for very good explanation. It is very well explained and this approach I will have in mind in future, but for this specific task, I'm not able to do that. I cannot group in early phase these tag names because it will affect other logic that is going on in solution. I can only work with that list in which I'm adding values.

Comment: @user3463933 Maybe you should take another look at it, because [Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) is exactly what you want, you want to group tag values by their names. If you require everything to be in that list, just make a list similar to how I had mine in the example. Plus, [Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) wouldn't affect your logic because it does not change the underlying data structure. You are just changing how it is presented, that's all.

Comment: Thanks again for contribution, but I'm still very sure that I'm not able to do that.I have to have dictionary as it is, and that, when I'm iterating through my permutations, I'm adding to list all values that are changed. And than, the last step would be to make that output as I explained. The order is very important in this whole process, so if I would grouped these values in beginning, I would lost whole point.

Comment: @user3463933 If you are using a dictionary, how are you getting duplicate tags? Dictionaries require that keys be unique, otherwise you'll get an exception. How are you building your dictionary?